# mysql / ajax: run mysql query on div click using ajax and return echoed data back to ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have the following form:

```
<form action="process_promo.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="promo" id="promo">
        <div class="promo_check"></div>
</form>
```

i am then using ajax to perform a check to see if the text entered in the promo input field matches that which is in my database with mysql.

heres my ajax:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '.promo_check', function() {
var promo = $("#promo").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("process_promo.php", {
promo1: promo,
}, function(data) {
if(data == 'wrong') {
alert('wrong');
}else{
if(data == 'correct') {
alert('correct');

} } }
});
});
});

</script>
```

and finally here's my mysql query in process_promo.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mark";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$promo = $_POST['promo'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM supplier_users WHERE promo_code = '$promo' AND username = 'mark'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {

echo "correct"; 
}else{
    echo "wrong";
}
?>
```

if the query returns true and the text in my input field matches the text in my database i am asking it to echo out 'correct' else if it returns false i am asking it to echo 'wrong' and then alert me of the relevant outcome in my ajax.

For some reason i am not getting any alert message and as far as i can tell nothing is happening.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard i am not sure how to do this, i am using Chrome on mac how would i do that?

Comment: Obvious question: have you loaded jQuery in your page?

Comment: @HoboSapiens yes i have loaded the following: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: `Command + Option + j` and check the network tab.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @MarcB i'm not too concerned with sql injection at this point, the sql i have provided is just as simple as can be for now until i can clarify why my ajax is not working. but duly noted thanks

Comment: @JamesGayle If that's actually what you've put in your page you are attempting to load two different versions of jQuery (Why?). Neither will actually load as you've omitted the protocol string so the browser will search for files in a relative URL. Remove one of those lines and add `//` to the start of the other

Comment: in that case, start basic web debugging: check your server's access log to see if you even get the ajax 'hit', check the jqHXR object returned from the .post() call afterwards and see if its .fail() came up. ditch the entier `if` in your return handler and just `alert(data)` to see what really came back from the ajax call - since you're doing extra string matches, ANY extra output (e.g. php warnings/errors) would cause your string comparisons to fail

Comment: @HoboSapiens are you sure? because when i use basic jquery functions like on page load: alert('hello'); this works with both the scripts in place?

Comment: `alert('Hello');` is not a jQuery function - it's just Javascript.

Comment: @HoboSapiens ok apologies, please see updated question with my jquery script sources attached at the top of my ajax code, which one is not needed? thanks

Comment: @JamesGayle It doesn't matter - they're both current versions. Use version 2.1.3 unless you're planning to support old versions of IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

- Include the latest version of the **jQuery** library *once only*.
- Add a button to your form and use `return false` to prevent the default
  submit event.
- Make sure you close your braces `{}` correctly in your jQuery. (You have an additional closing brace `}` in your jQuery)
- Add your `ajax` *above* your form.

Give this a try:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.promo_button', function() {
        var promo = jQuery('#promo').val();
        jQuery.post("process_promo.php", {promo: promo,},
            // Pass your variable (promo) to the function 
            function(promo) {
                // If your variable is empty
                if(!promo) {
                    alert('wrong');
                }
                else{
                    // Pass the results back to your page
                    jQuery('.promo_check').html(promo);
                } 
            }
        );
        // Prevent default form submit
        return false
    });
});

</script>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="promo" id="promo">
        <button class="promo_button">>></button>
        <div class="promo_check"></div>
</form>
```

Your PHP code looks OK and should run fine. However, you can add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php):

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

to the top of the php page to catch any pesky bugs.

Remember that you can use your Chrome's [network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) to check your POST requests. This can often help *a lot*.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please see Console log if there is any error...
do you have any syntax errors? 
is your post request recived by the server? if so , does your serve codeing any errors?
trying to use "console.log('some logging text')" to see whether the code is working correctly and reached there.